# Rails Formtastic Polymorphic Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I'm having issues with Formtastic not displaying information from a related table that has a has_many polymorphic relationship.

There are four models at play: NPC, Player, Ability, and Xref_Ability. But I'm only concerned with two at the moment: Player and Xref_Ability

I've gone against the naming convention for cross-reference tables because xref_ability is tied to NPCs as well as Players. See the model relations for Xref_Ability and Player below:

**Player**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :characterable
  ...
  has_many :xref_abilities, :as => :characterable
  #has_many :xref_abilities, :through => :characterable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :xref_abilities
end
```

**Xref_Ability** (cross reference table for abilities for NPCs and Players alike)

```
class XrefAbility < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ability_id, :characterable_id, :characterable_type

  #Validation
  validates :ability_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:characterable_id, :characterable_type]}
  #Relations
  belongs_to :ability
  belongs_to :characterable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I've added the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as many people seemed to have experienced issues without this included. However, once I include that, I couldn't use `:xref_abilities` in my input for loop; receiving the error: `uninitialized constant Player::Xrefability`. So I attempted to use :`characterable` and it returns null:

```
<div class="show">
  <%= semantic_form_for @Player do |f| %>
    <h1><%= @Player .name %></h1>
    <%= f.inputs %>
    <%#= f.input :characterable, :collection => XrefAbility.all %>
    <%= f.inputs :for => :characterables do |abil| %>
      <%= abil.input :ability_id %>
    <%  end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You can see I tried collection and that returned a drop down with all records... Not what I was looking for. I also tried doing .find_each instead of .all with conditions, which gave me a no block (yield) error.

I know it has something to do with the polymorphic relationship and how Xref_ability is not exclusive to Player. Nor does it have a direct relationship to Player. If I knew how to do this, then maybe I could solve the issue. I couldn't find anything on the gitHub so suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this modified stuff it should work.

```
<div class="show">
  <%= semantic_form_for @Player do |f| %>
    <h1><%= @Player .name %></h1>
    <%#= f.inputs %>
    <%#= f.inputs :characterable, :collection => XrefAbility.all %>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :characterables do |abil| %>
      <%= abil.inputs :ability_id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: semantic_fields_for and :for can be used interchangeably. It had the same result: null.